# Why is this border not visible?

Tags: html, css, border

On [this page](http://wowballoons.com/home.html), in the TESTIMONIALS section below the fold on the right, the content of the testimonial (the text in the `<article>` tag has a border:

```
.testimonial-entry.dark {
    background-color: #F6F6F5;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

Google Chrome's Developer Tools Computed Style viewer confirms that there really is a right border, that it's not being overwritten or anything:

```
border-right-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1.1111111405455043px;
```

Nevertheless, the right border is not visible. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Did we provide useful answers?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I was AFK.

Comment: Everyone's answers were correct.

Comment: Then you can give a +1 to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause the parent html elements like div's ul's gives your article not enough space in the width. There are now many soultions to get this work. clean solutions with more work and quick soultion with less work.

One quick solutoin can be to give your article a fixed width that it fit in the parents html elements. Line 844 in your http://wowballoons.com/wp-content/themes/nevada/nevada/style.css?ver=1.6

```
.testimonial-entry.dark {
    background-color: #F6F6F5;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    width: 316px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.testimonial-entry.dark` is going beyond your container. The right border is outside your container, and overflow is hidden, so you won't see it.

Make your article narrower.

`.testimonial-entry dark {width: 315px; }` should solve it.

Comment: It's not visible with overflow:Visible, either.

Answer (score 2):

Its not shown because the div is too wide and goes outside `.container`. The `section` containing it (`.one_half` `.last`) is `451px` wide and so is `.testimonial-entry.dark` but the `li` parent to it shifted it to the side.

**If** you change on your console the `li`'s CSS `margin-left: 18px` to `-1px` you will see it, actually the whole border.

Solution is to make your articles more narrow, the element you need to afect is

```
.single-testimonial_3 li {width:330px;}
```